# I need to be able to transfer call from Twilio Elastic SIP Trunk to Twilio Autopilot

Tags: twilio, 3cx

When a customer dials my Twilio number, I need Twilio to first try to call my PBX system. Currently using 3CX. If the call is not answered by a person, I need to find a way to send that call back to Twilio and go to another resource. For my purposes, that resource is Twilio AutoPilot.

Basically, if a human doesn't answer the phone, I want the robot to try and help the customer instead.

The only thing I've been able to come up with so far is to create another Twilio number and have that number be the fallback within the PBX. The problem with that solution is with Twilio, you cannot mask the number to match the CallerID of the customer calling in, and I would really like to be able to know that number. Also you are creating 2 call paths, which could make this an expensive option.

The only other solution I could think of, which would use 3 calls paths, would be to use another provider that does allow me to mask the caller id, and then send that to the Twilio number.

I am not a programmer, I have basic coding knowledge, but just barely.

Any help would be appriciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Programmable Voice with a SIP Dial to initially contact your PBX (it will appear the same way an Elastic SIP Trunk call will appear to your PBX). The easiest way is to use the Connect Call to Widget in Studio. If that call fails, say 3CX returns a 404 - Not Found, Studio can continue to the next Widget via the Connected Call Ended path which can then perform additional steps of your choosing. The CallerID is maintained this way as well.

Elastic SIP Trunking is not designed for this particular call flow but rather a simple conduit from/to the PSTN.

**Happy Path**
[image]

**Fallback Path**
[image]